# Refactor nested MySQL transaction in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I've a simple function like

```
function transfer_money($from, $to, $amount) {
    // START TRANSACTION 

    deduct_money($from, $amount); // already using transaction internally
    add_money($to, $amount); // already using transaction internally

    // COMMIT;
}
```

Suppose the functions `deduct_money` and `add_money` are already using transaction internally, how can I wrap the new function with another transaction?

Comment: Can you modify how `deduct_money` and `add_money` begin and end transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want your two function to continue using transactions as they are, but want to wrap a whole process in a "higher level" transaction, you can architect your own methods / functions to start and end transactions... Eg:

```
<?php 

class Transaction 
{
    private static $stack = 0;

    public static function begin(PDO $adapter) 
    {
        if(self::$stack === 0) {
            $adapter->beginTransaction();
        }
        self::$stack++;
    }

    public static function commit(PDO $adapter)
    {
        if(self::$stack === 0) {
            throw new Exception('Cannot commit as no transaction has begun');
        }

        self::$stack--;

        if(self::$stack === 0) {
            $adapter->commit();
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to "stack" transactions, and a transaction will only be commited when the same number of calls to commit the transaction have been recieved as the number to start the transaction.